# Typescript with AMD and require.js

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, requirejs, amd

I am using Typescript with AMD and require.js, but I cannot get the typescript compiler to output code which will be executed after loading the modules.

This is `main.ts`:

```
import { foo } from './bar';

foo('world');
```

This is `bar.ts`:

```
export function foo(name: string) {
  alert('Hello ' + name);
}
```

I compile this with the following `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "outFile": "client.js",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "files": [
        "main.ts"
    ]
}
```

And include it in my HTML like this:

```
<script data-main="client/client.js" src="/static/require.js"></script>
```

However, the generated JavaScript code looks like this:

```
define("bar", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    function foo(name) {
        alert('Hello ' + name);
    }
    exports.foo = foo;
});
define("main", ["require", "exports", "bar"], function (require, exports, bar) {
    "use strict";
    bar.foo('world');
});
```

Everything is fine, except from the fact that I would like to execute the code within the `main` module directly. So the last definition should be

```
define(["require", "exports", "bar"], ...
```

instead of

```
define("main", ["require", "exports", "bar"], ...
```

Currently, I would need a third script written in JavaScript just to load the `main` module, and I consider it bad style to have the `main` module as reusable code.

How can I get the typescript compiler to output `main.ts` as an executable definition instead of a module definition?

Answer (score 2):

`Function define` only defines a module, it will never execute the module irrespective of how code is generated by TypeScript.

After all modules have been defined, you have to execute a script, which should contain a statement calling `require` method.

So after your script has been loaded, you have have a script which should not be in AMD format, it should simply contain following statement...

```js
require(['main'], function (main) {
   // your main has been loaded !!!
});
```

Typescript will not generate such statement as it assumes all modules are in AMD format. However invoking and executing module is function of AMD loader, and caller should manually call and invoke the module.

Answer (score -5):

When you use 'import ...', TypeScript will compile AMD modules like displayed in your question. Could you try the following code ([also check this tutorial](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-amd-with-requirejs-tutorial/)) to verify if it results in the output you ask for?

```
/// <reference path="[YOUR IMPORT FILE]" />
/// ...

/**
 * Main entry point for RequireJS
 */
require(
    [
        // YOUR IMPORT DEFINITIONS
    ],
    (/* YOUR IMPORT VARIABLES */) => {
        'use strict';

        // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
);
```

Comment: Don't use `/// <reference path="[YOUR IMPORT FILE]" />` with modules. Just `import` them.